# Testing Kerberos with Docker Containers

Tags: docker, kerberos

I am setting up automated tests for a Kerberos authentication app. There will be three components: KDC, Service and Client. Should they be in separate containers, or can I group some of them together?

Using CentOS 7 and the service will be a Vertica database.